# Refresh data in Ionic abstract menu

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

In my application, operations can be performed. When a user performs an operation increases their number of points that are displayed in the menu my problem is that I can not update this result in the menu since when I do a state.reload () reload only the controller that I access but not the From the menu that is the SndController driver. I've tried putting `$ ionicConfigProvider.views.swipeBackEnabled (false);` But it does not work What can I do? I leave you the code of the menu and the one of app.js. Thank you

```
<ion-side-menu side="left" ng-controller="NavController">
          <ion-content has-header="true" class="menuscroll">
            <ul class="list" ng-show="currentState == 'menuconsumidor'">
              <h1 class="text-center title">¡Hola {{usuario.nombre}}!</h1>
              <div class="resumen-puntos puntosMenu"><i class="icon icoNivel {{claseNiveles}}"></i><span class="txtMenu">Tienes <span class="resaltado">{{usuario.puntos | commaToDecimal}} €</span> acumulados <br/>Tu nivel es <span class="resaltado uppercase">{{usuario.tramo}}</span></span></div>
              <a ui-sref="snd.datos" nav-clear class="item datos" ng-click="toggleLeft()"><i class="ion-android-person"></i>Datos personales<i class="ion-chevron-right"></i></a>
              <ion-item vinculaciones class="item vinculaciones"><i class="ion-android-people"></i>Vinculaciones<i class="ion-chevron-right"></i></ion-item>
              <a ui-sref="snd.niveles({reload: true})" nav-clear class="item niveles" ng-click="toggleLeft()"><i class="ion-ios-star-outline"></i>Niveles y Zonas<i class="ion-chevron-right"></i></a>
              <a ui-sref="snd.terminos" nav-clear class="item terminos" ng-click="toggleLeft()"><i class="ion-android-document"></i>Términos y condiciones<i class="ion-chevron-right"></i></a>
              <a ui-sref="snd.ayuda" nav-clear class="item ayuda" ng-click="toggleLeft()"><i class="ion-help-circled"></i>Ayuda<i class="ion-chevron-right"></i></a>
              <a ui-sref="snd.share" nav-clear class="item comparte" ng-click="toggleLeft()"><i class="ion-android-share-alt"></i>Comparte<i class="ion-chevron-right"></i></a>
              <ion-item  log-out class="item salir"><i class="ion-android-exit"></i>Salir<i class="ion-chevron-right"></i></ion-item>
            </ul>
            <ul class="list" ng-show="currentState == 'menucomercio'">
              <h1 class="text-center title">¡Hola {{usuario.nombreComercio}} !</h1>
              <div class="resumen-puntos puntosMenu"><i class="icon icoNivel {{claseNiveles}}"></i><span class="txtMenu">Este mes has facturado  <span class="resaltado">{{usuario.importeFacturadoMesActual | commaToDecimal}} €</span> <br/>Tu nivel es <span class="resaltado uppercase">{{usuario.tramo}}</span></span></div>
              <a ui-sref="snd.datoscomercio({reload: true})" nav-clear class="item datos" ng-click="toggleLeft()"><i class="ion-android-person"></i>Datos personales<i class="ion-chevron-right"></i></a>
              <a ui-sref="snd.nivelescomercio({reload: true})" nav-clear class="item niveles" ng-click="toggleLeft()"><i class="ion-ios-star-outline"></i>Niveles y Zonas<i class="ion-chevron-right"></i></a>
              <a ui-sref="snd.terminoscomercio" nav-clear class="item terminos" ng-click="toggleLeft()"><i class="ion-android-document"></i>Términos y condiciones<i class="ion-chevron-right"></i></a>
              <a ui-sref="snd.ayudacomercio" nav-clear class="item ayuda" ng-click="toggleLeft()"><i class="ion-help-circled"></i>Ayuda<i class="ion-chevron-right"></i></a>
              <a ui-sref="snd.share" nav-clear class="item comparte" ng-click="toggleLeft()"><i class="ion-android-share-alt"></i>Comparte<i class="ion-chevron-right"></i></a>
              <ion-item  log-out class="item salir"><i class="ion-android-exit"></i>Salir<i class="ion-chevron-right"></i></ion-item>
            </ul>   
          </ion-content>
        </ion-side-menu>
      </ion-side-menus>
```

Snd controller is my menu in my application .

```
.state('snd', {
        url : '/snd',
        templateUrl : 'templates/snd-abstract.html',
        abstract : true,
        cache: false,
        controller : 'SndController'
    })
    .state('snd.home', {
        cache: false,
        url: '/home',
        views: {
            'snd': {
                templateUrl: 'templates/snd-home.html',
                controller : 'SndHomeController'
            }
        }
    })
    .state('snd.terminos', {
        cache: false,
        url: '/terminos',
        views: {
            'snd': {
                templateUrl: 'templates/snd-terminos.html',
                controller : 'SndEstaticasController'
            }
        }
    })
    .state('snd.ayuda', {
        cache: false,
        url: '/ayuda',
        views: {
            'snd': {
                templateUrl: 'templates/snd-ayuda.html',
                controller : 'SndEstaticasController'
            }
        }
    })
    .state('snd.operaciones', {
        cache: false,
        url: '/operaciones',
        views: {
            'snd': {
                templateUrl: 'templates/snd-operaciones.html',
                controller : 'SndOperacionesController'
            }
        }
    })
    .state('snd.detalleoperacion', {
        url: '/operaciones/:operacionId',
        cache: false,
        views: {
            'snd': {
                templateUrl: 'templates/snd-detalle-operacion.html',
                controller : 'SndOperacionDetalleController'
            }
        }
    })
    .state('snd.nivelescomercio', {
        url: '/nivelescomercio',
        cache: false,
        views: {
            'snd': {
                templateUrl: 'templates/snd-comercio-niveles.html',
                controller : 'SndNivelesComercioController'
            }
        }
    })
    .state('snd.ofertascomercio', {
        url: '/ofertascomercio',
        cache: false,
        views: {
            'snd': {
                templateUrl: 'templates/snd-comercio-ofertas.html',
                controller : 'SndOfertasComercioController'
            }
        }
    })
    .state('snd.nuevaSedeComercio', {
        url: '/nuevaSedeComercio',
        cache: false,
        views: {
            'snd': {
                templateUrl: 'templates/snd-comercio-nueva-sede.html',
                controller : 'SndNuevaSedeComercio'
            }
        }
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

I resolved . I push this code in my parent state...

```
$scope.$on('$ionicView.beforeEnter', function() {

    console.log(' reload state before enter children state');
    $scope.usuario = UsuarioFactory.getUsuario();
    console.log(usuario);

});
```